# Laravel queue jobs not retrieving model in handle

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Every time I dispatch a job the values passed in `ProcessJob::dispatch($model_object)` are not available in the `handle()` method of the `ProcessJob` class

I tried passing just the id of model record but it's still not available in the `handle()` of the `ProcessJob` Class

```php
public function __construct(int $id)
{   
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->links = collect([]);
    $this->phone_numbers = collect([]);
    $this->emails = collect([]);
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $columns = [];
    logger($this->id);
}
```

I was expecting the `logger($this->id)` to log the id number but it doesn't.

id comes from

`ProcessJob::dispatch($crawler_job->id)->onQueue('crawler');`

Comment: Are you 100% confident that the $crawler_job->id is a int? What happens if you just remove the 'int' in the (int $id)

Comment: if I run dispatchNow() it logs the ID number.

Comment: Let me try it again.

Comment: I think it worked. Double checking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be figuring out how it works by now. Just a quick tip:

You may not need to pass the model id into the job. Just pass the whole model object and use the SerializesModels trait.

```
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

ProcessJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $model;

    function __construct(TestModel $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

}
```

So when the job is serialised, the model id will be stored in the payload instead of the the whole object.